# Smallest expressible value above given value

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits, numeric-limits

Given a variable defined as

`T x;`

where `T` is a generic arithmetic type (i.e. such that `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value`), is there a simple expression (e.g something from `std::numeric_limits`) that evaluates to the lowest value `y` expressible in `T` such that `y` > `x`?

(i.e. a kind of generalized increment..)

Comment: Should be possible if you treat bool as a special case. According to docs is_integral<T> is the type bool, char, char8_t, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, short, int, long, long long and all of those support an increment except bool. So seems very possible.

Comment: @systemcpro The trickier part are the floating point types which are also arithmetic. Just incrementing is not sufficient though, a range check is required, because a value satisfying the condition may not exist.

Comment: Yes, hence I cheated and used is_integral and not is_arithmetic. Am such a fraud.

Comment: Need to package something like `std::nextafter` into a type-generic template.

Comment: Could you clarify your question on 1. whether you assume as precondition for `x` that an `y` satisfying the condition exists or what should happen if no such `y` exists and 2. whether infinities need to be handled correctly, e.g. when `x` is negative infinity or `x` is the largest finite value?

Comment: @uneven_mark In my case UB is ok if there is no representable next value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::nextafter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter).

Note that here I use `std::numeric_limits<Floating>::max()`, if you want meaningful behavior for infinities, you might want to modify the code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Floating,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Floating> && !std::is_integral_v<Floating>, bool> = false>
Floating generic_next_val(Floating val) {
    return std::nextafter(val, std::numeric_limits<Floating>::max());
}

template <typename Integral,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Integral> && std::is_integral_v<Integral>, int> = 0>
Integral generic_next_val(Integral val) {
    return static_cast<Integral>(val + static_cast<Integral>(1));
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    float f = 0.0f;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << generic_next_val(f) << " " << generic_next_val(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `<cmath>` header's [`std::nexttoward()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) will do this. It accepts a float, double, long double, or integral type, and returns the next value in the direction of its second parameter.

So, given code like this:

```
T my_val = some_input; // float, double, int, etc.
T next = std::nexttoward(my_val, std::numeric_limits<T>::max());`
```

If `my_val` were 1.0f, `next` would be the next biggest float after 1; if `my_val` were the integer 2, you would get 3, etc.

(Note that there's a lot of fine print here around numeric overflows, which the CppReference page linked above discusses. The long and short of it is don't pass `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` in for the first parameter.)

Comment: Why `nexttoward` rather than `nextafter`? You are also ignoring the integral types completely, which will not give the correct result with this approach.

Comment: `nexttoward()` because unlike `nextafter()`, it has an overload for integral types. :)

Comment: `nextafter()` also has overloads for all integral types, see (4) on the cppreference page. But neither of these do the correct thing, because the integral types are cast to `double` first in these overloads.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

/*
NOTE: Untested code for 'proof' of concept only.

This will cover all the is_integral<T> except bool.

This should probably be a set of free functions rather than a class
but just to check out the idea. Class should have constraints but as
the final implementation should probably be free functions they are
omitted.
*/
template<typename T>
class GLB{
public:
    using limits = std::numeric_limits<T>;

    static T get(const T& value){
       return value == limits::max() ? limits::max() : value + static_cast<T>(1);
    }
};

int main(int, char**){

    std::cout << GLB<int>::get(42) << '\n';
    std::cout << GLB<unsigned>::get(42) << '\n';
    std::cout << GLB<wchar_t>::get(42) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

/*
 That was the easy bit now what about the floating point numbers.
*/
```

While fooling around with this scur3 pointed out that cmath can solve the floating point values. So some typing and some testing required.